# Use index of specific element to get an item from another list (lambda notation)

Tags: java, lambda

I've searched online and didn't find any answer. I can do it with for-loops, but for readability I tried it with lambda notations, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I've got a list of strings and a list of lists with strings.
When I give a string name and a string value, it should search through **vars** for that string, and when it has a match (lets say on index 2) it should go through **probabilities** and on each list in this list check if the value on index 2 is equal to the given string value. If it is it should delete the index, if not it should delete the whole list (one element of **probabilities**). I can do this with for-loops as follows:

```
private ArrayList<String> vars = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> probabilities = new ArrayList();
private String v_name = "coughing";
private String v_value = "positive";

public void someFunction(){     
    for(int i=0; i<vars.size(); i++){
        if(vars.get(i).equals(v_name)){
            for(int j=probabilities.size()-1; j>=0; j--){
                if(probabilities.get(j).get(i).equals(v_value)){
                    probabilities.get(j).remove(i);
                } else {
                    probabilities.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in short, I was wondering if it is possible to do this with Lambda notations, since I couldn't find an example where you search for an element in a list, and look in other lists at the index the element was found. Paired with deletion in a list where you are iterating over I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, as `getName()` is not a valid method for `int`.

Comment: @JacobG. I've changed it. This isn't my original code since there are some other things it needs to do but they are irrelevant for the question so I changed it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Define minimal `ProbRow` and `Variable` used above.

Comment: I've changed the code, is it better now?

Comment: This looks more like an XY problem. Meaning: if this operation is really that important, than coupling your lists using *indexes* sounds wrong. You see, instead of having different lists, and **knowing** that index x in list A somehow corresponds to index x in list B ... that is very fragile. I would step back, and look at the problem that got you to these lists, to then solve the whole thing in a different way.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I'm not seeing how I would implement this any other way. I've simplified the code in the problem above, since it is actually from a Bayesian network where this is one variable. The first list is its parents and the second list are the values of each variable with a type double probability. Nevertheless I'm still curious if this type of problem is doable in lambda notation, since I couldn't do it.